# homebrew edit with sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, homebrew

I'm trying to execute the `brew edit` command. However, apparently Homebrew can't find the path to sublime, which is my default editor:

```
$ brew edit mongodb
--: subl: command not found
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

I'm using the latest Homebrew on OSX Yosemite beta.

Comment: Homebrew looks at the environment variables HOMEBREW_EDITOR, VISUAL and EDITOR. Check to make sure these point to Sublime.

Comment: @NOP-- `$VISUAL` and `$HOMEBREW_EDITOR` are unset. `$EDITOR` returns `-bash: subl: command not found` which is odd since I can execute the `subl` command from the prompt and it opens sublime.

Comment: What is `echo $EDITOR`? `$EDITOR` by itself is just try to execute it...

Comment: @Amadan-- returns `subl`

Comment: Just a thought, but its probably running in its own environment as a sub-shell to launch that, so its not on your path.  Have you tried setting `$EDITOR` to the full path, e.g. by doing a `which subl` first to get it?  e.g. `export $EDITOR=`which subl``.  Thats assuming subl isn't an alias.  On my box sublime is in `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2`

Comment: @user101289: What does `which subl` return? It seems like you're pointing it to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: `which subl` returns nothing, I assume because `subl` is an alias.

Comment: @user101289: If `subl` is an alias, `brew` won't be able to find it. Set `$EDITOR` to the full path to `subl` instead.

Comment: @mipadi-- what's the best way to set environment vars in mavericks? I've found many contradictory explanations. Thanks